# Pull values from all database row's for calculations

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I have implemented a Database in my project and following several tutorials, have been able to pull data and display in listviews. I, however, have not been able to search and find a solution to my current problem.

I have two columns in a table. The columns are: **TABLE_UNITS** and **TABLE_PRICE** and they are in the table **TABLE**. I want to display a combined portfolio of sorts where each rows, UNITS and PRICE have to be multiplied and this sub total will be added for each row present in the database. To make it clearer:

UNITS ---- PRICE ---- **TOTAL**

50------------5-----------**250**

20------------10----------**200**

GRAND TOTAL ------- **450**

So the question is, how do I pull all this information into, say a string, and then calculate and then get the next row, do the same calculation and get the Grand Total?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps this query can help you:

```
Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT TABLE_UNITS, TABLE_PRICE,
           (TABLE_UNITS * TABLE_PRICE) AS TOTAL FROM table;", null);
```

for grand total, you need to run a separate query:

```
Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT SUM(TABLE_UNITS * TABLE_PRICE) AS GRAND_TOTAL
           FROM table;", null);
```

Comment: Should I run this as a 'rawQuery' in my DB helper class?

Comment: Your edit gave me an idea. And now it works. I had absolutely forgotten about a TOTAL column in the TABLE and your suggestion did it for me. And now I feel like a complete ass. :-) Thanks for the help fella. :-)